# How to mask coloring cells using another list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Here is the example data/script I am working with. As shown below, I am trying to mask/highlight values in a list of data frames, test, based on values from another list of data frames, test2. I've been trying to figure out the best way to map coloring based on another list, test2. I included the example/code illustrating the issue I am having below but please let me know if anything is not clear. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
#Creating a set of dataframes
data = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],'item_name': ['hp', 'logitech', 'samsung', 'lg', 'lenovo'],
        'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],'item_name': ['hp', 'mac', 'fujitsu', 'lg', 'asus'],
        'price': [2200, 200, 300, 450, 200]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],'item_name': ['microsoft', 'logitech', 'Average', 'lg', 'asus'],
        'price': [1500, 100, 200, 350, 400]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

#Creating another set of dataframes
data = {'product_name': ['Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Excellent', 'Excellent'],'item_name': ['hp', 'Excellent', 'Excellent', 'Average', 'Excellent'],
        'price': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
dv1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'product_name': ['Average', 'Average', 'Average', 'Average', 'Average'],'item_name': ['Excellent', 'mac', 'Excellent', 'lg', 'Average'],
        'price': [10, 20, 30, 50, 50]}
dv2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {'product_name': ['Excellent', 'Average', 'Excellent', 'Better than Average', 'Better than Average'],'item_name': ['Excellent', 'Average', 'Average', 'lg', 'asus'],
        'price': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
dv3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

#creating a list for dataframes
test=[df1,df2,df3]
test2=[dv1,dv2,dv3]

#combining two lists
zipped = zip(test, test2)
zipped_list = list(zipped)

#the final output should go here
final=[]
for x in zipped_list:
    def apply_color(val):
        colors = {'Excellent': 'green',
              'Better than Average': 'olive',
              'Average': '#fdee73', 
              'Worse than Average': 'pink', 'Low':'pink',
              'Very low':'red'}
        return x[1].applymap(lambda val: 'background-color: {}'.format(colors.get(val,'')))
        z=x[0].style.apply(apply_color, axis=None)
        final.append(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation in your last two lines is incorrect, this otherwise seems to work as you intended:

```
final=[]
for x in zipped_list:
    def apply_color(val):
        colors = {'Excellent': 'green',
              'Better than Average': 'olive',
              'Average': '#fdee73', 
              'Worse than Average': 'pink', 'Low':'pink',
              'Very low':'red'}
        return x[1].applymap(lambda val: 'background-color: {}'.format(colors.get(val,'')))
    z=x[0].style.apply(apply_color, axis=None)
    final.append(z)

final[0]
```

Comment: Hi mozway, thanks so much for providing this! It's helpful. I think this would provide the same coloring for each dataframe. The first dataframe, final[0] should not have the same coloring as final[1] and final[2]. Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: If I remove the for loop, ```def apply_color(val):
    colors = {'Excellent': 'green',
              'Better than Average': 'olive',
              'Average': '#fdee73', 
              'Worse than Average': 'pink', 'Low':'pink',
              'Very low':'red'}
    return test2[1].applymap(lambda val: 'background-color: {}'.format(colors.get(val,'')))
z=test[1].style.apply(apply_color, axis=None)``` this would give a different coloring/mask. This is what I am trying to do, to have dynamic coloring for each dataframe.

Comment: mozway, I posted another question relating to this. Could you take a look and let me know if it provides what you need?